# split(regexp_replace ) Like Function In Presto : 331

Tags: hive, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

Is there any way to split values based on consecutive 0's in presto.Minimum 6 digits should be there in first split, if digit count is less than 6 than need to consider some 0's as digit then split if digit count is  >= 6 then just need to split in 2 groups.
below query is working as expected in Hive.But I am not able to do the same using presto.

```
 select low as orginal_Value,
 split(regexp_replace(low,'(\\d{6,}?)(0+)$','$1|$2'),'\\|')  Output_Value  from test;
```

[image]

**Presto Query:**

```
presto> SELECT regexp_split('1234567890000', '(\d{6,}?)(0+)$') as output;

output
[1234567890000]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked Now.

```
select split(regexp_replace('1234567890000','(\d{6,}?)(0+)$','$1|$2'), '|') as output;
enter code here
   
output
-------------------
[123456789, 0000]
```